# Can RabbitMQ (or similar message queuing system) be used to single thread requests per user?

Tags: rabbitmq, mq

The issue is we have some modern web applications that are integrated with a legacy system that was never designed to support multiple concurrent requests from a single user.  Basically there are certain types of requests that the legacy system can only handle one-at-a-time from a single user.  It can handle multiple concurrent requests coming from different users, but for technical reasons cannot handle multiple from a single user.  In these situations, the user's first request will complete successfully, but any subsequent requests from that same user that come in while the first request is still executing will fail.

Because our apps are ajax enabled, multi-tab/multi-browser friendly, and just the fact that there are multiple apps - there are certain scenarios where a user could wind up having more than one of these types of requests being sent to the legacy system at the same time.

I'm trying to determine if something like RabbitMQ could be positioned in front of the legacy system and leveraged to single-thread requests per user/IP.  The thinking being that the web apps would send all requests to MQ, and they'd stack into per-user queues and pass on to the legacy system one at a time.

I don't know if there would be concerns about the potential number of queues this could create - we have a user-base of approx 4,000.

And I know we could somewhat address this in the web apps individually, but since there are multiple apps it'd be duplicating logic across them, and you'd still have the potential for two different apps to fire off concurrent requests.

Any feedback would be appreciated.  Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a unique queue per user will work as you would need to have a backend worker process listening for messages on that queue that would need to be dynamically created.

Below is one option but it does have a performance bottleneck potential as a single backend process would be handling all requests sequentially. You could use multiple worker processes but you wouldn't know if one had completed before the other causing a race condition if your app requires a specific sequence of actions.

You could simply put all transactions (from all users) into a single queue and have a backend process pull off of that queue and service the request. If there needs to be a response back to the user once the request was serviced, then the worker process could respond back to a separate queue with a correlationID that could be used to send the response date back to the correct user.

I've done this before with ExpressJS apps where the following flow would happen:

1. The user/process/ajax makes a request
2. Express takes the payload from the `request` object and sends it to a RabbitMQ queue with a unique `correlationId` (e.g. UUID).
3. Express then takes the `response` object and stores it in a `responseStore` object with the key being the `correlationId`
4. Meanwhile, a backend worker process pulls the item from the queue, does some work and then sends a message to a different response queue with the same `correlationId`
5. The ExpressJS application has a connection to the response queue and when it receives a message, it takes the `correlationId` from the response and looks for a `response` object stored with same `correlationId` in the `responseStore`. If it finds it, it takes the payload from the message and does something like `response.send(payload)` or `response.json(payload)`

To do this, you should also have a mechanism that stores the creation time of the `response` object in the `responseStore` along with the `response` object. Then have a separate process that will check the `responseStore` and clean up old response objects after a certain timeout in case there are issues with the backend process completing.

Look here for more info on RPC with RabbitMQ:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-javascript.html

Hope this helps.